# Define a sub query outside of the main query for easiler readability

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is the a way to define a sub query outside of the main query so the sql code becomes easier to read? For example:

Instead of this:

```
Select * 
From 
    Select * 
    From 
        Select *
        From TableName
```

I want:

```
Select *
From A

Define A = Select * From B
Define B = Select * From TableName
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 if that's relevant.

Comment: Please look in to Common Table Expressions (CTE).  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try something like this. with Common Table Expressions.

```
;

WITH B
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TableName
    )
    ,A
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM B
    )
SELECT *
FROM A;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with views (which I think is more in line with what you are asking than CTE:

```
CREATE VIEW B AS (Select * From TableName);
CREATE VIEW A AS (Select * From B);

SELECT *
FROM A;
```